# Remove a line of text and the next 0 to 5 lines with powershell 2

Tags: powershell, text

I am using powershell and would like to delete a line of text based on a match and then a certain number of lines after the line with the match. I have the following code which will delete the current line with a match. How do I remove the next line(s)?

Get-Content $filePath | ? {$_ -notmatch "`f"} | Set-Content $outPath

Comment: You need to explain your objective a little better.  For example "the next 0 to 5 lines" based on what?  A variable setting? something in the match?

Comment: The above example would remove any line from a text file if a form feed was found on that line. I want to remove a specific number of lines after the matched line in order to strip each new page header, leaving me with one continuous document without form feeds and page headers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this is longer, it may be a useful base if you have more complex "rules" to determine which line to remove. (I prefer @mjolinor's answer though)

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$Source,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$Target,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Int32]$Lines
)

$LinesLeftToRemove = 0
$TargetContent = @()

(Get-Content $Source) | % {
    If($_ -notmatch "`f") {
        $LinesLeftToRemove = $Lines + 1
    }

    If($LinesLeftToRemove -GT 0) {
        $LinesLeftToRemove--
    } Else {
        $TargetContent += $_
    }
}

Set-Content $Target $TargetContent
```

Note that this should be put in a `SomeScript.ps1` file and used like this:

```
.\SomeScript.ps1 -Source .\Source.txt -Target .\Target.txt -Lines 5
```

Comment: Note that if your source file is large, you'd be better using a StringBuilder; more details here: http://powershell.org/wp/2013/09/16/powershell-performance-the-operator-and-when-to-avoid-it/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work for you or not, but it may be something you can modify to match your data:

```
$inputfile = <input file>
$outputfile = <output file>
$skipafter = <number of line to skip after pattern match>
$pattern = <pattern to search for>

$regex = [regex]('.*?' + $pattern + ('.*?\r\n' * ($skipafter + 1)))

(Get-Content $inputfile -raw) -replace $regex | set-content  $outputfile
```

Comment: My guess is that without the raw parameter (i am using PS 2) I will not be able to use this?

Comment: Sure you can. `(Get-Content $inputfile | Out-String)`