# Remove line in text file if it contains string and then remove the next two lines

Tags: powershell

I tried [Remove a line of text and the next 0 to 5 lines with powershell 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297285/remove-a-line-of-text-and-the-next-0-to-5-lines-with-powershell-2) but that removed everything in my script.

I'm building a PowerShell script to parse an LMtools output. 
I have a line that takes out anything that is not in use

```
$body = (($body -split "`n") |
        Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'Total of 0 licenses in use'}) -join "`n"
```

I don't need to see packages in use as the following two licenses show exactly what is in use.

I need to remove lines with Users of Package: and the two following lines.

So this:

```
Users of Package: Autodesk AutoCAD:  (Total of 1 license issued;  Total of 1 license in use)
  "Package: Autodesk AutoCAD" v1.000, vendor: adskflex, expiry: permanent(no expiration date)
    UserH ybw-w7-15021 ybw-w7-15021 (v1.000) (licenseserver/27000 490), start Mon 2/25 10:38
Users of Package: AutoCAD - including specialized toolsets:  (Total of 1 license issued;  Total of 1 license in use)
  "Package: AutoCAD - including specialized toolsets" v1.000, vendor: adskflex, expiry: 15-feb-2020
    UserA DC18007-W10 DC18007-W10 (v1.000) (licenseserver/27000 114), start Mon 2/25 10:50
Users of Autodesk AutoCAD 2017:  (Total of 4 licenses issued;  Total of 1 license in use)
  "Autodesk AutoCAD 2017" v1.000, vendor: adskflex, expiry: 15-feb-2020
    UserA DC18007-W10 DC18007-W10 (v1.0) (licenseserver/27000 214), start Mon 2/25 10:50
Users of Autodesk AutoCAD 2015:  (Total of 4 licenses issued;  Total of 1 license in use)
  "Autodesk AutoCAD 2015" v1.000, vendor: adskflex, expiry: permanent(no expiration date)
    UserH DCw7-15021 DCw7-15021 (v1.0) (licenseserver/27000 390), start Mon 2/25 10:38
```

just becomes this:

```
Users of Autodesk AutoCAD 2017:  (Total of 4 licenses issued;  Total of 1 license in use)
  "Autodesk AutoCAD 2017" v1.000, vendor: adskflex, expiry: 15-feb-2020
    UserA DC18007-W10 DC18007-W10 (v1.0) (licenseserver/27000 214), start Mon 2/25 10:50
Users of Autodesk AutoCAD 2015:  (Total of 4 licenses issued;  Total of 1 license in use)
  "Autodesk AutoCAD 2015" v1.000, vendor: adskflex, expiry: permanent(no expiration date)
    UserH DCw7-15021 DCw7-15021 (v1.0) (licenseserver/27000 390), start Mon 2/25 10:38
```

Comment: your code that creates this file implies that each group of 3 lines _started out_ as _one_ line. is that true?

Answer (score 1):

You could read the input line by line and then skip lines matching "Users of Package:" and the next two lines. However, since your entire input file seems to consist of groups of 3 lines I'd probably use `Select-String` with a negative lookahead assertion.

```
$pattern = '^Users of (?!Package:)'
Get-Content 'input.txt' | Select-String $pattern -Context 0,2 | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Line
    $_.Context.PostContext
} | Set-Content 'output.txt'
```

The pattern matches the string "Users of " at the beginning of a line (`^`) when it is not followed by the string "Package:".

Using `-Context 0,2` includes the subsequent two input lines with the match.

Comment: @SomethingSysadmin Is `$body` a single string? That won't work. You need the input as an array of lines.

Comment: That did the trick, whats a good way to change that from a file into $body?

Comment: @SomethingSysadmin See above. ;) You could split `$body` at newlines to get the required input.

Comment: Hmm, I am splitting the lines in other places, maybe i can do something similar. https://pastebin.com/0FPcSqzW